# Capture screen on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I saw a cool feature on [slack](https://slack.com/) that allows to share screen between users (like teamviewer or skype). But I can't find anywhere documentation how to capture a screen (e.g. on chrome). It seems slack does it without any extension, so it should be integrated into browsers.

Can anyone please provide me a link to documentation or throw me an exampe.

Comment: Hmm.. Firefox recently added it too

Comment: There is an alternate way to do so using Developer Tools. Check out http://www.thewindowsclub.com/take-screenshots-chrome-firefox-browser

Comment: I beleave you misunderstood me, I don't need to record a screen from developer tools or take a screenshot. I want to record a window from javascript and then send the stream over a network or webrtc.

Comment: Okay, so what you want to know is the API used to capture window in Chrome...

Comment: In that case [chrome.desktopCapture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture) might be useful

Comment: @AmitSingh Thank you, that's exactly what I needed, if you post is as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`chrome.desktopCapture`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture) API offered by Chrome is useful to capture screen content, individual tabs or windows.

Comment: I have the latest chrome and `chrome.desktopCapture` is undefined from site.  It's available from chrome extension tho, but apps like https://meet.google.com/ don't require an extension to capture the screen. Is there something I can do to access desktop capture from site?